# Password must be minimum 8 characters including 1 uppercase letter,1 lowercase 1 special character( from: !, @, #, $, %, ?, &)

Tags: c#, regex

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\!\@\#\%\&\*).{8,25})
```

this is my regular expression, the problem with it is the (?=.*!\@#\%\&*)

the password is supose to look like this : Za1#gbe1&

Any tip would be really great!
PS: its because I was training myself with segex cuz  I suck at it

Comment: Why use a singular monolithic regular expression? This can be easily described with several different conditionals (which might use regular expressions). Also, this is a really backwards password requirement with low security. A much better rule: 16 characters, anything you want, preferably "correct horse battery staple" (google it).

Comment: Not the same cuz he doesnt have a a specify special key like mine

Comment: The `a-z` can be swapped out with any characters. There's nothing unique about special characters vs lowercase characters. Use the same syntax for the special characters.

Comment: wow your rigth thanks im dumb